# Loading sonata_type_colletion field via ajax

Tags: sonata-admin

I'm using sonata admin in my project I have two entities, Order and Delivery which are related in a oneToMany relationship. Each of these has a oneToMany relationship with OrderItem and DeliveryItem respectively.

I would like to make it easier when creating a Delivery by loading corresponding Order Items by pre-populating the items delivered through an ajax call based on Order item selected.

I extended the edit theme and can make the ajax call which populates fine, however when trying to save, I get the error in relation to my form having extra fields even though I've followed sonata admin's naming convention to the letter.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when calling `formMapper->add()` you can pass the `'allow_extra_fields' => true` option.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields

Comment: can't believe it was this easy considering the amount of code I wrote to solve this issue

Comment: Glad it helped.Please consider accepting my answer so others may benefit from it.Happy programmming!